# Laravel 5.3 Validation: Unique period time which is set by two column (start_date, end_date)

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5

Is there any way to validate the unique period times which is set by two column (start_date, end_date)? Please let me know if this is possible by using Laravel 5.3 validator.

Thanks
Arvi

Comment: Who set these columns? Where are these column set from?

Comment: They are from database table.

Comment: So you want the difference to be unique? can you paste some code or test case which you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far as I know there is no way to accomplish such complex custom rules on Laravel. I understand that you really wanna do some thing like this:

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////
// This is not working code. just an idea !!!
//
$data['period'] = $data['start_date'] . "-" . $data['end_date'];
        $validator = Validator::make($data, [    
            'period' => Rule::unique('projects', DB::raw('concat(start_date, "-", end_date)')),
        ], [
            'period' => 'Period is duplicated.',
        ]);
```

But Larvel does not accept this kind of rule (actually I am wondering why they do not accept this kind of approach)

So you have 2 options.

**Solution 1.** Create a view in the database, which will have additional column "period" which is made by concat(start_date,"-",end_date).
And then make the code like following.

```
$data['period'] = $data['start_date'] . "-" . $data['end_date'];
        $validator = Validator::make($data, [    
            'period' => Rule::unique('projects', DB::raw('concat(start_date, "-", end_date)')),
        ], [
            'period' => 'Period is duplicated.',
        ]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
  // do some thing
} else {
  unset($data['period']); // When adding or update, 'period' will cause error because period is only in view, not in table itself
  // do insert or update
}
```

**Solution 2.** Just pass normal validation except for the unique checking, after all validation done, you do checking yourself by searching in the table manually.
Like following:

```
if (Project::where(DB::raw("concat(start_date, '-', end_date)"), "=", $data['start_date'] . "-" . $data['end_date'])->count() > 0) {
  // now this is not unique, so do something
}
```